# Write a query more efficient, mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

Tables:

```
A,B,Animal,Car
```

Attributes:

```
A:LinkingID, AnimalID, CarID

B:LinkingID, AnimalID, CarID

Animal:AnimalID, Name , Breed

Car:CarID, Weight
```

What I want:

Select those As and Bs for which:

```
A.LinkingID=B.LinkingID

(Animals with AnimalID same as A.AnimalID).Name = (Animals with AnimalID same as B.AnimalID).Name

(Animals with AnimalID same as A.AnimalID).Breed = (Animals with AnimalID same as B.AnimalID).Breed

(Animals with AnimalID same as A.AnimalID).Color = (Animals with AnimalID same as B.AnimalID).Color

(Cars with CarID same as A.CarID).Weight = (Cars with CarID same as B.CarID).Weight
```

The query I've written:

```
    select * from A dzo 
     inner join B sar 
        on dzo.LinkingID = sar.LinkingID
     inner join Car c1
        on c1.CarID = dzo.CarID
      inner join Car c2
        on c2.Weight = c1.Weight
        and c2.CarID = sar.CarID
      inner join Animal v1
        on v1.AnimalID = dzo.AnimalID
      inner join Animal v2
        on v2.Name = v1.Name
        and v2.Breed = v1.Breed
        and v2.AnimalID = sar.AnimalID

;
```

Can a more effiecient query be written?

Comment: Kind of weird to use table aliases longer than the table names themselves :)

Comment: This is efficient, if a little odd - WHERE z = x AND z = y is the same as writing WHERE y = x AND z = y, which is a little more usual. For more help, provide SHOW CREATE and EXPLAIN SELECT statements

Comment: Why do you have two tables (A & B) with an identical schema? If A and B represent two different types of links, then perhaps merge those tables and add a `type` column with `A` and `B` values?